# Why is the max size for the boot USB drive 32GB for unRAID OS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nas

I am assuming this is related to the file system the drive is formatted with, but I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Also, why do they limit the installation of unRAID to only a USB and not traditional boot media (e.g. an SSD)? I know they use the GUID of the drive for license purposes, but surely they could use some other form of HWID. It would definitely be more professional/reliable than a USB boot.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is the max size for the boot USB drive 32GB for unRAID OS?

The developers have specified this limitation, and it is documented in [Hardware Recommendations for System Builders](https://lime-technology.com/guidelines-for-system-builders/):

> **USB Flash Device**
>
> unRAID Server runs entirely from RAM, minimizing writes to the Flash
>   device; however, it is also used to store vital system configuration
>   data and must remain installed in your server during operation. **In
>   addition, to obtain a registration key for unRAID Server OS, your
>   flash device must contain a unique GUID (Globally Unique Identifier)
>   and needs to be at least 512MB, but no larger than 32GB in size**. 
>   Also, please make sure you are using a well known brand and not using
>   a card reader.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [Guidelines for System Builders - Lime Technology](https://lime-technology.com/guidelines-for-system-builders/)

If you want to know **why** you should ask on their [General Support](https://lime-technology.com/forums/forum/55-general-support/) forum, as only the developers can answer this.

---

#### Why do they limit the installation of unRAID to only a USB and not traditional boot media (e.g. an SSD)?

That is a question you should ask on their [General Support](https://lime-technology.com/forums/forum/55-general-support/) forum, as only the developers can answer this.